# How to get event properties

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, eventkit

I have the following method, for getting all events in the current day:

```
- (NSArray *)fetchEventsForToday {

    NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];

    // endDate is 1 day = 60*60*24 seconds = 86400 seconds from startDate
    NSDate *endDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:86400];

    // Create the predicate. Pass it the default calendar.
    NSArray *calendarArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:defaultCalendar];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [self.eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startDate endDate:endDate calendars:calendarArray]; 

    // Fetch all events that match the predicate.
    NSArray *events = [self.eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];

    NSLog(@"array: %@", events); 
    return events;
}
```

If I check my NSLog I get the following  object in the array:

```
2011-06-29 19:24:01.383 SimpleEKDemo[2945:207] array: (
    "EKEvent <0x5118cd0> { EKEvent <0x5118cd0>   {
        title = Test; 
        calendar = EKCalendar <0x5105d60> {
            title = Calendar; 
            type = Local; 
            account = (null); 
            allowsModify = YES; 
            color = 0.443137 0.101961 0.462745 1.000000
        }; 
        alarms = (null); 
        URL = (null); 
        lastModified = 2011-06-29 23:51:51 +0000
        }; 
        location = (null); 
        startDate = 2011-06-30 00:30:00 +0000; 
        endDate = 2011-06-30 01:30:00 +0000; 
        allDay = 0; 
        floating = 0; 
        recurrence = (null); 
        attendees = (null)
    }",

    "EKEvent <0x5118380> {EKEvent <0x5118380>   {
        title = Prueba; 
        calendar = EKCalendar <0x5105d60> {
            title = Calendar; 
            type = Local; 
            account = (null); 
            allowsModify = YES; 
            color = 0.443137 0.101961 0.462745 1.000000
        }; 
        alarms = (null); 
        URL = (null); 
        lastModified = 2011-06-29 23:51:58 +0000}; 
        location = (null); 
        startDate = 2011-06-30 00:30:00 +0000; 
        endDate = 2011-06-30 01:30:00 +0000; 
        allDay = 0; 
        floating = 0; 
        recurrence = (null); 
        attendees = (null)
    }",

    "EKEvent <0x5117f70> {EKEvent <0x5117f70>   {
        title = Numero; 
        calendar = EKCalendar <0x5105d60> {
            title = Calendar; 
            type = Local; 
            account = (null); 
            allowsModify = YES; 
            color = 0.443137 0.101961 0.462745 1.000000
        }; 
        alarms = (null); 
        URL = (null); 
        lastModified = 2011-06-29 23:53:54 +0000}; 
        location = (null); 
        startDate = 2011-06-30 00:30:00 +0000;
        endDate = 2011-06-30 01:30:00 +0000; 
        allDay = 0; 
        floating = 0; 
        recurrence = (null); 
        attendees = (null)
    }"
```

As you can see I have 3 object: "test", "Prueba" and "Numero" this title and the start and end date is all information that I need, but I don't know how to get it. Does anybody can help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the documentation for [`EKEvent`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventClassRef/Reference/Reference.html)? The required properties are

1. [`title`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/EKEvent/title)
2. [`startDate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/EKEvent/startDate)
3. [`endDate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/EKEvent/endDate)

#### Usage

```
NSArray *events = [self.eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];
for ( EKEvent * event in events ) {
    NSLog(@"Title: %@, Start Date: %@, End Date: %@", event.title, event.startDate, event.endDate);
}
```